# How to write a script to launch Thinkorswim

Tags: shell-script, shell, sudo

I am trying to make a script that automatically launches Thinkorswim from a simple command in the terminal. I wrote an incredibly simple script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sh /opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
```

This is in the /usr/bin directory so I can just type `thinkorswim` in the terminal. The application requires sudo to run, and I want to make it so I don't have to type in `sudo`, and then my password. This is partly just for speed and convenience, and partly because I want to be able to launch it through dmenu on i3.

1. I have tried putting `echo password | sudo sh...` in the script. This does not work.
2. I have tried adding `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim` to sudoers, after adding `sudo` before `sh` in the script. This does not work.
3. I have tried adding `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/thinkorswim` to sudoers. I quickly realized that I would still need to type `sudo` before `thinkorswim` when lauching it through the terminal, and this still does not work through dmenu.

I restarted my computer after I modified sudoers each time. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with i3wm version 4.17.

TL;DR: I am trying to run a script with sudo permissions without actually having to type `sudo` and my password. How do I do this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where exactly are you using `sudo`? If you put `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim` in `sudoers`, then you need to be using `sudo /opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim`

Comment: In that case, I modified the script to say `sudo sh /opt/think...`, that way sudo was being executed on the `/opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim`.

Comment: No it's not, `sudo` is executed on `sh` in that case.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

Comment: But I have to use the `sh` program to execute `/opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim`. I thought I was using `sh`, with sudo permissions, to launch `/opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim`

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it, posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a pretty easy fix. Thanks to user [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) for helping. I made the script say this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sudo /opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
```

Then added this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
```

`sudo` was running on `sh`, not on the file itself. Everything works perfectly now, this will save me alot time every day. Thanks again to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru).